# Building Linux C++ with VSTS

Tags: c++, linux, docker, azure-devops

I'm trying to build a C++ app for Linux using VSTS. The build is defined by the Docker container template, and the Agent queue is Hosted Linux.

When running, I get 
    [error]Unhandled: No Docker file matching  /opt/vsts/work/1/s/**/Dockerfile  was found.

How do I create the Docker file requested by the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that there isn’t the **Dockerfile** file existing in working folder, you can include the **Dockerfile** file in the source control and map to the agent (Get sources of build definition)

There is the Docker image that shared by others, for example: [madduci/docker-ubuntu-cpp](https://hub.docker.com/r/madduci/docker-ubuntu-cpp/) and the CMake generated files will be in build folder, if you just need to build the C++ project, you can refer to these steps (CMakeLists.txt is in the root of the repository):

1. Add Docker task (Action: `Run a Docker command`; Command: `run -v $(Build.SourcesDirectory):/project madduci/docker-ubuntu-cpp`)
2. Publish Build Artifacts (Path to publish: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/build`)

If you need to build the docker image, you need to create Dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks. I just need to build the C++ project. I have added the `Run a Docker command` with `run -v $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/LinuxConsoleApplication madduci/docker-ubuntu-cpp` and created a CMakeLists.txt file in the root of the repository. However I get `Status: Downloaded newer image for madduci/docker-ubuntu-cpp:latest
CMake Error: The source directory "/project" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
Error: could not load cache`. Ideas?

Comment: Using run `-v $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/LinuxConsoleApplication:/project madduci/docker-ubuntu-cpp` instead, it will copy the files in $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/LinuxConsoleApplication to project folder of docker container. Note: the CMakeLists.txt is under LinuxConsoleApplication folder.

Comment: @EricaC What's the result now? Do you solve this issue?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. I'm very grateful. I didn't post an answer due to the advice not to reply with thank yous in the comments box... I don't agree with this policy...

Answer (score 0):

When the Docker task is set to Build an image you get an option to specify a Docker file:

[image: Docker file for building an image]

`**/Dockerfile` means that the task will search your repository for a file named Dockerfile and use that to build the image.

The error you get means that this file can't be found. You can find some examples of Dockerfiles [here in the Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/). [This blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/08/developing-linux-c-applications-with-azure-docker-containers/) describes how to build C++ applications that run on a Linux container